# Conda export giving useless .yml file

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I'm working with an environment named `gcloud`, with many google APIs packages installed. I wanted to export said environment to install it elsewhere, but when I do that I get a very useless .yml file. I run:

```
conda activate gcloud
conda env export > gcloudenv.yml
```

Which brings this:

```
name: gcloud
channels:
  - defaults
prefix: C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\envs\gcloud\envs\gcloud
```

So there's no libraries listed, even though I have installed many. What could be happening?

This is `conda list`'s output:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\jeco_\Anaconda3\envs\gcloud:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py37_1
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
bzip2                     1.0.7                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cachetools                2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
conda                     4.7.5                    py37_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.18.7                   py37_0
conda-package-handling    1.3.11                   py37_0
cryptography              2.7              py37h7a1dbc1_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
google-api-core           1.13.0           py37h21ff451_0    conda-forge
google-api-python-client  1.7.9                      py_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.6.3                      py_0    conda-forge
google-auth-httplib2      0.0.3                      py_2    conda-forge
google-cloud-core         1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-storage      1.16.1                     py_0    conda-forge
google-resumable-media    0.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
googleapis-common-protos  1.6.0            py37h21ff451_0    conda-forge
httplib2                  0.13.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.1            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.3.3                h0643e63_5
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.9.0                h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libxml2                   2.9.9                h464c3ec_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.0                     py37_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0
protobuf                  3.9.0            py37he025d50_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.3            py37he774522_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pyasn1                    0.4.5                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_10
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1
qtconsole                 4.5.1                      py_0
qtpy                      1.8.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
rsa                       3.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
simplejson                3.16.0           py37hfa6e2cd_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0
soupsieve                 1.8                      py37_0
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.4                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.0                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
tqdm                      4.32.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
uritemplate               3.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: What is the output of `conda list -n gcloud` (or just `conda list` with the environment activated)?

Comment: Added the output. I'm guessing it might have to do with environment.yml prefix listing ..\envs\gcloud\envs\gcloud instead of just ..\envs\gcloud

Comment: Yes, that's very strange. Can you try `conda env export -n gcloud -f gcloudenv.yml`?

Comment: Woah, that worked, but the formatting of the file was odd. Changed it to `conda env export -n gcloud >  gcloudenv.yml` and the format was fixed. Do you have any ideas of what was happening?

Comment: Nope, sorry! It might be a bug in conda :-)